PHP or Xdebug character encoding error when encountering an Exception in Xdebug
I have encountered some error in VSCode with Xdebug. Sometimes the Exception message is not represented as UTF-8 so I can't understand the error message.
I've set the character encoding to UTF-8 in both php.ini and VSCode.
What should I do to translate it to UTF-8?


I guess the problem is related to this moodle_exception class, there's nothing to do with xdebug or php.

Try disabling Xebug to see If the exception message shows correctly or is still the same.

@Olivier ok i’ll try it.
