VSCode Xdebug exception message encoding issue - Korean language
I'm using Xdebug in VSCode on Windows 10.
When I debug PHP source using Xdebug, Character Encoding for Exception Message is weird.  My Source File Encoding is UTF-8, and php.ini configuration is also UTF-8.
I don't know why Xdebug emits Exception message broken encoding.  I attached some screenshot for Exception Message, first one is VSCode Exception Message and the other is error log in PHP.
I think origin message is "잘못된 사용자 id" in second image. For some reason, VSCode or Xdebug can't interpret Korean.
Where's this problem coming from?


I checked character encoding in php.ini, it's UTF-8. And source code file encoding is also UTF-8.
Origin exception message is in Korean. And VSCode or Xdebug can't interpret Korean, so I think one of these can't interpret Korean or UTF-8.
Is there any options to set character encoding in VSCode or Xdebug?


You have asked the same before, 25 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78860275/php-or-xdebug-character-encoding-error-when-encountering-an-exception-in-xdebug



I'd enable Xdebug log ( https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log ), try to debug to reproduce the issue and check the log -- see what encoding it uses there (you might  need to force the UTF-8 encoding for a file). If it's OK there -- it might be VSCode then... I would then suggest to contact the Xdebug VSCode extension author about this (he/she should know more about it)

